# Designing XtraDB cluster

Tags: mysql, percona, galera, mysql-cluster, percona-xtradb-cluster

We have an application which consists of microservices all connected to the same Percona DB instance. Currently it is just one instance with 16 cores/32 GB memory without replication. One of our issues is that sometimes one of our microservices causes such high load on the database (even just reading) which makes all the microservices unusable.

We are thinking about creating a Percona cluster of three nodes with choosing nodes for each microservice. The services which mostly "write" would connect to one instance and the rest would connect to the other two instances. This way if some microservice causes high load with reads, it shouldn't completely overwhelm our infrastructure.

My questions:

1. Is this even good idea? Shouldn't we rather let ProxySQL deal with splitting the traffic? ProxySQL would porbably mean no isolation.
2. Should we rather have more instances with less CPU or rather less instances with more CPU? Having more instances would mean more isolation for running microservices in case of high load.
3. Is it a good idea having nodes with different CPUs? For instance let the "writing instance" have more CPU in comparison with the "reading instances".
4. If we direct microservices to "their Percona instance", can we still have some kind of HA when their instance completely dies?

Note: We would probably use Percona XtraDB click-to-deploy in GCE: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/percona?project=goout-cloud&folder&organizationId=74390800864

Comment: What kind of query do you have? Can't it be optimized?

Comment: We have thousands of queries and sometimes there is one which is not optimized. Sometimes we have peaks of visitors - from 500 online we can get tens of thousands. Then this one single query "kills" the whole db. Of course we will identify that query and optimize it, but I am looking for something to prevent these accidents.

Comment: You have an account over at dba.stackexchange.com Why don't you post the question there? This site  is for programmers.

Comment: Also, are you sure you have more visitors at certain times, or is just the thread count rising because your ominous query holds some locks? Have you investigated the slow query log during such times? Did you have a look at the output of `show engine innodb status\G` when the query is killing the server? In my opinion your priority should be to find the query and optimize it, not think about clusters (yet).

Comment: We sell tickets to events and when some sale is launched we can get thousands of visitors at one time, whereas we have around 500 people online normally. So yes, we have these peaks.

Comment: @fancyPants There are 529,430 questions on stackoverflow just for MySQL alone. This site is not *only* for programmers.

Comment: @utdrmac There's a difference between questions that regard to sql (and mysql specific functions and so on) that programmers use, and administration of a database. This question is clearly not directed at programmers, but for administrators. When you pull up some facts, please do it right.

Comment: The complexity of dedicating nodes for particular tasks will probably be folly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, this is a good idea. Using ProxySQL with PXC is also a good idea. By using ProxySQL, you can: A) implement "writer" HA by putting two nodes into the same hostgroup, one with super high weight (10000000) and the other at low (10). If high-weight node goes offline, ProxySQL will seamlessly start sending traffic to the other node. B) put all nodes into a separate "reader" hostgroup with the same weights, thus load-balancing write traffic. C) If desired, create a 3rd hostgroup with just 1 node and create a query-rule to pattern match on schema, user, or query pattern for your "high load" query and direct execution to that specific node. ProxySQL will also let you cache some of those heavy-hitting queries.
2. Personally, I would pick less instances with higher CPU unless you know your network is rock solid. In PXC, all nodes must synchronously ACK all transactions. The more nodes you have, the longer the latency those operations can take. The fastest you can commit is the time between the two slowest nodes. Please make sure you always have an odd number of nodes, unless you get advanced with the pc.weight setting (but that's super tricky to get right).
3. With MySQL in general, all nodes should be the same configuration. If your master is more powerful than slaves, generally speaking, slaves will not be able to keep up with the volume. With PXC, this means you will experience flow-control events more frequently which can translate to application stalls. If node2 cannot write as fast node1, node2 sends out flow-control messages, (cries for help), asking the other nodes to slow down while it catches up.
4. Yes, using ProxySQL as described in #1.

Side note, query optimization is the #1 way to "speed things up." Don't always throw hardware at the problem. It is worth the time to examine your slow query log and attempt to improve queries. Sometimes, a single index can make a night/day difference.

*Disclaimer: I'm Percona's Senior Instructor and have delivered numerous full-day PXC and ProxySQL intensive tutorial sessions.*

Comment: Thanks for detailed response, this is very helpful. One more question: If we have high write load on one of the servers, will the synchronization consumes the same load on the other masters or will it be optimized, so it will be less cpu consuming?

Comment: @Vojtěch High write load on node1 == high write load on all nodes. (Side node, this is not a limitation of MySQL; all RBMS would be affected like this.) If you insert 1000 rows on node1, all other slave/stand-by nodes must also insert 1000 rows in order to remain in sync. In Async replication, you can optimize somewhat by using row-based replication over statement-based; you can use 'minimal' binlog event size but the end result is still the same. This is a common misconception that many available writers in a cluster/group equals increased write capacity.

Comment: "Odd number of nodes" for Galera (aka PXC) is not a requirement; it's a myth.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may need to address the "Critical Read" scenario via `wsrep_sync_wait`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your **spikes** are the problem.  And you need to process the flood as fast as possible, since users are expecting to get those hot tickets.

Adding a **queue** only adds complexity *and slows down the processing* when the actions are fast.  So "Don't queue it, just do it."  Further note that the queue would be transitionally replicated to the other nodes, thereby making the enqueue/dequeue possibly slower than simply acting on the request!

A connect - **do something** - disconnect takes time.  A lot of the time is not really involved in the "something", but rather overhead around it.  I find that if less than about 10 connections are active, things run smoothly.  But if more than 10 manage to get started, then InnoDB starts to stumble over itself.

Ever been in a **crowded store**?  Let's say there is room for 200 people and carts in all the aisles.  But if you try to have 210 shoppers, everyone is slowed down just trying to jockey for a position.  Throughput decreases, perhaps to the point of people wanting to abandon their cart an leave.  Ever see a store with a line out front?  They solved the problem by not allowing more than 200 simultaneously shoppers!

So, the solution to your problem may be **outside MySQL**.  If you have a web page fronting MySQL, throttle it to limit the number of 'threads' it is using.  Apache, for example, has such, plus a "backlog" for queuing up at the connect-to-Apache level.  MySQL have `max_connections` and `backlog` that possibly work the same way, but the default for `max_connections` (151) is too high.  151 students crowded around the soda machine in a convenience store may be a better analogy.

**More** nodes / more CPUs may *or may not* be part of the answer; it depends on what locks are taken out by the "something".

**Monitor** `Threads_running`; if it grows to more than a few dozen, then I suspect my comments apply.  If the monitor program can't connect to check that `GLOBAL STATUS`, then I know it applies.